# Auto rename symbolic link

Tags: linux, find, ln

I have a folder which contains many sub-folders which contains many images. I find it tedious to go into each folder to browse the images so I decided to create an empty folder and create symbolic links to all of the images with the following command (I'm on Ubuntu 11.10):

```
find /home/someuser/ParentImageFolder/Galleries/ -iname "*.jpg" -print -exec ln -s {} . \;
```

This works fine but the problem I am running into is that if there are two files with the same name in different folders, only one symbolic link gets created.

Can anyone provide a way for me to solve this so that even if there are two files with the same name, I will still get two symbolic links created when I run my command above.

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, but why don't you just symlink the whole folders inside the galleries? This way you wouldn't need to bother about the file names: 
`find /wherever -type d -exec ln -vs {} . \;`   (or something like that)

Answer (score 1):

Add `--backup=numbered` to ln and `.~n~` will be appended if a name already exist.